# Illegal string offset for 'url' when using WordPress Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am converting a Bootstrap template into a WordPress theme.

For custom fields I am using the plugin **[Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)**. The issue is when I am trying to add an image with the help of **Advanced Custom Fields**, I get the following error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\wamp64\www\my-site\wordpress\wp-content\themes\bootstraptowordpress\page-home.php on line 31

However when I am adding text through this plugin it shows **no error**.

I have no other plugins installed other than ACF.

Here is my code:

```
$home_page_logo = get_field('home_page_logo');

<div class="front_logo">

   <?php if( !empty($home_page_logo)): ?>

      <img src="<?php echo $home_page_logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php  echo $home_page_logo['alt']; ?>" />

   <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways that an image field can be returned in ACF (array, URL, or ID). It sounds like your field is set to return the URL - which returns as a string.

Therefore, you need to access it like this:

```
<?php echo $home_page_logo; ?>
```

instead of this:

```
<?php echo $home_page_logo['url']; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can edit the set up for the field in your WordPress admin and configure it to return an image array instead of the URL:

[image]

If it's set to the array option, you can access the `url` like you are currently doing so, as well as access a range of other data pertinent to the image (such as its width and height, WordPress attachment ID, caption if entered, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Tim Malone. I solved this problem by second method mentioned by you

Answer (score -6):

It's better to use gravity forms plugin. You can to download here:
[Rocket Genius Gravity Forms WordPress Plugin](https://gpldl.com/repository/premium-wordpress-plugins/)

But if want to fix your code, try to test if is array:

```
<?php
$yes = array('this', 'is', 'an array');

echo is_array($yes) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
echo "\n";

$no = 'this is a string';

echo is_array($no) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/function.is-array.php